# express.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: insert into "table"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, knex.js

node.js server code:

```
const uploadAction = (req, res, db) => {
    const { 
        name, address, phone, email, password, photo, accesses, verified
    } = req.body;

        if (!name || !address || !phone || !email || !password || !photo || !accesses) {
            return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
        }
    
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);

        db.transaction(trx => {
        trx.insert({
            name:name,
            address:address,
            phone: phone,
            email: email,
            password: hash,
            photo: photo,
            permissions: accesses,
            verified: verified.toString()
        })
        .into('action')
        .then(site => {
            return res.json({"code":200, "id": site[0]});
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
        })
        // .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to fetch'))
    
    }
```

React.js frontend code:

```
    submitForm = () => {
    const { accesses, name, address, email, phone, password, confirm_password, photo, check } = this.state;

    let url = FormatUrl(`/actions`);
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          accesses: password,
          email: email,
          accesses:accesses,
          name: name,
          address: address,
          phone: phone,
          password: password,
          photo: photo,
          verified: check
      })
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if(res.code === 200){
          Toast.notification({ description: 'login success', type: 'success' });
        } else {
          Toast.notification({ description: 'failed', type: 'error' });
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        Toast.notification({ description: 'failed', type: 'error' });
      })
  }
```

error:

```
    (node:23763) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: insert into "action" ("address", "email", "name", "password", "permissions", "phone", "photo", "verified") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) - malformed array literal: "{"sites":["create","update","view"],"isp":["create","update","view","delete"],"ipam":["view","delete"],"topology":null,"floor plan":null,"rack":["view"],"devices":null,"outage tracker":["create"],"guides":["create","update","view","delete"]}"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/keyboo/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:241:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/keyboo/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:89:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/keyboo/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:41:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/keyboo/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    (node:23763) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
    (node:23763) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here i am trying to insert some data to postgres data base using express.js . I am using knex as postgres client
and from frontend i am sending all data.

But, I am getting above error.
Earlier worked in same was but, not able to understand error what is happening here
Please have a look

Comment: You are getting a warning because you don't have a catch block. And your code is raising an error (which you aren't `catch`ing) because of a `malformed array literal` - which means the format or syntax of an array is not correct ([Read this](https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/app-errors/U114))

Answer (score 0):

If that `permissions` is a jsonb field you should do `JSON.stringify(accesses)` when inserting.

Also you don't need explicit transaction for single insert since postgres does implicit transaction for single queries.

And better way to write that transaction would be:

```
db.transaction(trx => {
  // returning promise / thenable (which will be resolved to a promise) 
  // from transaction handler tells knex to implicitly commit if the promise
  // resolves fine or rollback if it rejects. 
  return trx('action').insert({
            name:name,
            address:address,
            phone: phone,
            email: email,
            password: hash,
            photo: photo,
            permissions: accesses,
            verified: verified.toString()
        });
})
.then(site => {
  // transaction was implicitly committed by knex with success
  res.json({"code":200, "id": site[0]});
})
.catch(err => {
  // transaction was implicitly rolled back by knex
  res.status(400).json('unable to fetch');
})
```

Though I have no idea where that unhandled promise error is coming. It is not clear from the code.